# checked = true, from earlier checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a question regarding the checkbox. 
I have 2 html pages. In the first one, there are checkboxes, which can be checked by the user. After pressing the submit button, the second page loads containing the same checkboxes, which now should be checked="true", if the user checked them in the first html page.
How can I do this second html page? I assume I have to use expression language. My project is made with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf as expresison language.

Comment: what you tried so far

Comment: I tried to do a if-statement, which didn't work out. I'm thinking of saving the checkboxes of the first page in a cookie and then load in the second page the values of the cookie in the second checkbox.
But I'm not sure, if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use local storage to set if your checkboxes are checked. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Note: users with multiple windows open to your site will get very odd results with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Get the elements that are set to true, put them in local storage and call them on second page. Happy to provide code, if you show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I tried that: 

<span th:each="kategorie : ${kategorien}"><label><input type="checkbox" name="kategorie" th:value="${kategorie.kid}" th:checked="((${kategorie.kid} == ${kategorie.kid}) ? true : false)"/><span th:text="${kategorie.name}">Kategoriename <br /></span></label><br /></span>

And this checkes every checkbox. I know that it doesn't really make sense. But thanks for the suggestion with the local storage. 
Now my question is how to save only the checked values?

Comment: Just do an if statement. if checkbox == true then store it.